# How to redefine the \partial command to adjust the kerning (as suggested by Michael Spivak)?

Tags: math-mode, kerning, computer-modern, latin-modern

Michael Spivak talked about this issue in his *Math Font Quiz*:

[image]

(Original article:
https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-3/distract/mathquizAnswers.pdf)

[image: fg]

In Latin Modern (and in Computer Modern Unicode as well), the space between `\partial` and `f` is too large, and looks rather ugly (I don't know if this is a flaw in kerning, because `\partial f` also looks bad, which shouldn't be the case). I want to redefine `\partial` in such a way that the kerning is automatically corrected.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\kernadjust{\kern -0.12em}
\let\@oldpartial\partial
\renewcommand\partial{\@oldpartial\@ifnextchar f{\kernadjust}{}}
\makeatother
```

This is what I have got so far: I managed to correct the kerning where `\partial` is immediately followed by an `f`.
But I don't know how to correct the kerning when `\partial` is used with superscripts/subscripts (e.g. `\partial^2 f`, `\partial_x f` or `\partial^2_{xy} f`).

So my question is:
How to redefine `\partial` in LaTeX to have the following behavior:

- When `\partial` is followed immediately by an `f`, or has a superscript/subscript in between, reduce the space in between by `\kernadjust` (I tested all the letters, only the letter `f` has this issue);
- Otherwise, use the default kerning (do nothing).

Comparison:

Unadjusted:

[image]

Adjusted:

[image]

Comment: If somebody wants to do the quiz before looking at the answer, it is available [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/distract/mathquiz.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no kerning in Computer Modern and quite likely Spivak was referring to `mathtime`. Here I use `mtpro2` to show the kerning.

You can absorb the function name, compute the standard kerning and insert it. I also remove the `\scriptspace` when there is a superscript.

However, no correction should be done in presence of subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff}{e{^_}m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{% subscript
    \partial\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}_{#2}#3
  }{% no subscript
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no superscript
      \partial#3%
    }{% superscript
      {\mathpalette\pdiff@{{#1}{#3}}}%
   }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff@}{mm}{\pdiff@@#1#2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff@@}{mmm}{%
  \begingroup
  % get the kerning
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\partial#3$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1{\partial}\kern0pt{#3}$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\wd\z@-\wd\tw@-\scriptspace\relax
  \partial^{#2}\kern\dimen@#3
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\pdiff{f}$ $\partial f$

$\pdiff^{2}{f}$ $\partial^{2}f$

$\pdiff^{2}_{x} f$ $\partial^2_{x}f$

$\pdiff^{2}_{xy} f$ $\partial^2_{xy}f$

$\pdiff{g}$ $\partial g$

$\pdiff^{2}{g}$ $\partial^{2}g$

$\pdiff^{2}_{x}{g}$ $\partial^{2}_{x}g$

$\pdiff^{2}_{xy}{g}$ $\partial^{2}_{xy}g$

$\scriptstyle \pdiff{f}\pdiff^2{f}$

$\scriptstyle \pdiff{g}\pdiff^2{g}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same code except for `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` produces

[image]

Comment: Are the calculations made possible via `LaTex3` only?

Comment: @projetmbc You might reimplement the `e` type argument.

Comment: I was talking about `\pdiff@@`.

Comment: @projetmbc Just translate. I don't see any need to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach for Latin Modern (and CMU) inspired by @egreg's answer:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\adjustvalue{-2.43mu}
\newcommand\kernadjust{\mkern\adjustvalue}
\let\@oldpartial\partial
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff}{e{^_}m}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% subscript
        \@oldpartial\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}_{#2}#3
    }{% no subscript
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no superscript
            \@oldpartial\ifx#3f\kernadjust\fi#3%
        }{% superscript
            {\mathpalette\pdiff@{{#1}{#3}}}%
        }%
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff@}{mm}{\pdiff@@#1#2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdiff@@}{mmm}{\@oldpartial^{#2}\ifx#3f\kernadjust\fi#3}
\renewcommand\partial\pdiff
\makeatother
```

(Notice I changed the adjust value to -0.135em (which is equal to -2.43mu), I find this value better than the -0.12em and -0.15em before)

I choose to redefine `\partial` rather than defining a new command because I want it to be compatible with existing documents (that is, I can paste the code to a pre-existing document without changing the content of the document). If you don't want this behavior, you can delete the `\renewcommand\partial\pdiff` line and use `\pdiff` instead.

Here is a comparison:

Unadjusted:

[image]

Adjusted:

[image]

However, the code above has some limitations: it can't handle anything between `\partial` and the letter `f`, such as `\partial \dot f` (which will not result in the correct kerning). I am still working on it, and I will post it as soon as I find a solution.

**EDIT:** The code is changed to handle the case with both superscripts and subscripts. The measure of kerning adjustment is changed to mu instead of em (thanks @egreg for the edit).

Comment: I've added support also for subscripts.

Comment: `-0.15em` better to use `mu` in math (1/18 em at textsize but adjusts in scripts)